# How to tell doxygen to use /** as class doc instead /*! \class

Tags: php, doxygen

I'm trying to switch from phpDocumentor to doxygen, but all my classes are documented in the following style:

```
/**
 * DESCRIPTION
 *
 * @category  PHP
 * @package   UserManagement.Class
 * @author    Name <email@company.com>
 * @copyright 2011 Company
 * @link      http://www.company.com
 */
```

but doxygen does not recognize that as the class doc unless I change the first line to

```
/*! \class CLASSNAME
```

Is there a  way to tell doxygen to use the "/**" style?

regards

Comment: Sort of off-topic; but if you're sick of PHPDocumentor - like I am - you might want to consider looking at [DocBlox](http://www.docblox-project.org) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem (but not the real solution): Doxygen does not like the @category & @package in the class doc block. If I remove them it works.

Comment: if you are on PHP 5.3 you should be able to use namespacing to provide this functionality (a bit of a hack but will probably provide the functionality you need) of course depending on situation this may/may not be possible with what you have

Comment: In fact if `@category` and/or `@package` are present the class detailed description can be found in the _Namespaces_ section in generated documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Doxygen should recognise JavaDoc (i.e. /**) comments. The problem maybe that your short description aren't being auto-detected.

To make Doxygen use these short descriptions you need to set [JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_javadoc_autobrief) to `YES` in your config file.

For more on how Doxygen documentation style have a look [at this](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html)

Comment: JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF is enabled and it does recognise them for functions but not for classes. So the "Detailed Description" of the documentation is empty.

Comment: @chrfin what does it display then for classes?

Answer (score 1):

If for example your co-workers still use phpDoc you can use the `INPUT_FILTER` configuration to filter unwanted tags away:

```
$ grep INPUT_FILTER doc/doxygen.config
INPUT_FILTER      = /home/gorgo/someproj/doc/doxygen.inputfilter
```

The inputfilter script must be executable and its content can be something like this:

```
$ cat doc/doxygen.inputfilter
#!/bin/sh

grep -Fv '@package' $1 | grep -Fv '@category'
```